# Apex Data Loader problem

Tags: apex, custom-object, data-loader, insert

I am trying to insert data into a custom object. My MD field with Contacts is Email__c. I want to use the email to identify the contact as is the unique identifier for my custom object. ( like when you insert in dataloader.io and for the contact id you select look via email).

Is it possible to do that on apex data loader? Whenever I try I get an error like Contact: id value of incorrect type: xxxxxx@xxx.com

I have 100k records to insert into 60k Contacts. Replacing their email with SF contact's id will take alot of time

Comment: An export and a vlookup on email doesn't take that long to build a file (I've done it with millions of records), and it's the only way I'm aware of to accomplish what you are attempting.  Unless you make a field an ExternalID value, you have to use ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that - but the external Id field needs to be on the Contact which you then reference in the data load. You can't use the standard email field for that though - so you would need to create a new field on Contact called something like Email_Reference, mark it as an external id, and then populate it with the email on the contact - probably via workflow or a trigger. Then when you load in your data via the dataloader, you can select upsert, choose email_reference as the lookup reference, and map your email field in your data to that reference.